# Таблица в MySQL

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Как очистить таблицу в MySQL? Это надо сделать через PHP-скрипт (не через phpMyAdmin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте, если вы умеете работать через phpmyadmin, то там можно посмотреть пример кода после выполнение действие. Также рекомендую научится пользоватся поиском. [Как почистить таблицы в базе данных в SQL](http://www.oracloid.ru/index.php?t=1536)

или 
[Чуть погуглить](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83)

**Ответ:** `mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE название таблицы");`

Comment: @MrGons18, там даже можно посмотреть пример кода на PHP

Answer (score 1):

> TRUNCATE TABLE `tablename`

Comment: спасибо. Сработало.